# The uploaded image shows up as image icon on html website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to build my portfolio. I want to add my picture to about me section. Although I do not get any errors, only the image icon shows up on the website

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjbCy.png)

and Here is my code for js:

```
            <div className="about__img">
                <img src="./images/br.jpg" class="me"/>
            </div>
```

I also tried uploading from image folder by using relative path
and this is for css

```
.me{
  position: relative;
   width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #f9f7f7;
    padding: 15%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0.7;
    -webkit-transition: border-radius 0.5s, opacity 0.5s;
    transition: border-radius 0.5s, opacity 0.5s;
}
.about__img{
  padding: 100px;

}

.about__img img{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

Can somebody please help!!
Check this to see where my folders are
[Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u91Rh.png)

Comment: This happens if you provide an invalid image src...

Comment: I edited my questions with the relative path option still the same result

Comment: Make sure to place the html file and images folder at the same level.

Comment: This error shows, that the picture is not found. please provide the data structure of your project. Maybe the relative path is incorrect? Or your picture is saved as .png and not -jpg? Could be lots of reasons...

Comment: Check what the browser console has to say. If it shows a 404, then the path is simply still wrong. Another possibility would be that the image itself is faulty (could have been messed up during upload to the server for example), so that the browser can not successfully decode it.

Comment: `br.JPG` != `br.jpg`. It also seems like you should move your `images` directory to the `public` directory, as your build system might do something...

Comment: That is where I opened the images file first but I couldn't access to images that why I put it into src

Comment: when I click on 'inspect'  on the browser it doesn't give me any errors

Comment: The best way to make sure your picture is visible is to go to imgbb
Once you have uploaded select the "HTML full linked" option and only copy the image source into your code. Here are the benefits I've found using imgbb.
 - You don't have to download images on your  computer saving storage 
- Your images are accessible anywhere 
- You can use the image links in code playgrounds as well

Comment: imgbb worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is showing that the image file cannot be found, try this:

```
 <div className="about__img">
                    <img src="../images/br.jpg" class="me"/>
                </div>
```